# How to change scope back to original function after calling a “local” function within module.exports in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to call another local function 'MessageScoring' within another function 'NextMessageCalculation' which are both in module.exports, however I am having trouble with getting the scope to change back. The function successfully calls the other local function, however the scope is then changed and variables in the previous scope all return undefined now. How would I fix this or is there a better way to call the local function to avoid this?

```
module.exports = {
   MessageScoring: function(){
    var attrs_list = Object.keys(message_attr_obj);
    var score = 0;
    for (i in attrs_list){
            if(user_data[attrs_list[i]]){
                score = score + user_data[attrs_list[i]]["beta"];
            }
            else{
                //user has no response with that attr yet so score is not added
            }
    }
    score = score / attrs_list.length;
    return score}... //returns an int

   NextMessageCalculation: function(){ //has a call to a mongodb and the logic takes place in the callback
MESSAGE_collection.find({'message_set':user_data.message_set,'id':{$nin:[1111]}}).toArray(function(err,doc){
                 if (doc.length === 0)
                   {
                        USERDATA_collection.update({phone:phone_num},{$set:{send_message:false}},function(err,res) {
                           db.close()
                        });
                   }
                    else{
                        var highest_score = "";
                        var next_message = "";
                        for (i in doc)
                        {
                            console.log(doc[i]['id']);
                           var score = module.exports.MessageScoring(doc[i].attr_list,user_data);
                           console.log(doc[i]['id']); <---- becomes undefined here after calling scoring function which correctly returns int 
                            if (highest_score === "")
                            {
                                console.log(doc[i]);
                                next_message = doc[i].id;
                                highest_score = score;
                            }
                            if (highest_score < score)
                            {
                                next_message = doc[i].id
                                highest_score = score;
                            }
                            console.log(doc[i].id);
                        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code? Unclear what MessageScoring does, or where d, i, and doc variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use function hoisting, step out from the modules.expors closure, and be sure that MessageScoring doesn't mutate data.

```
module.exports = {
   MessageScoring,
   NextMessageCalculation: 
}

function MessageScoring() {

}

function NextMessageCalculation(){
  const d = [{ id: 'ok' }];
  const i = 0;
  console.log(d[i]['id']); //returns ok
  var score = MessageScoring(doc[i].attr_list,user_data);
  console.log(d[i]['id']); //returns ok
}
```

Comment: my issue is that d and i are defined within NextMessageCalculation so i do not think this method will solve for that

Comment: Even better, the scope is smaller. It seems that MessageScoring mutates data.

Comment: is it because i am not using const? the d or doc is the input from the mongodb callback function. should i set it to a const ?

Comment: i get the same issue when setting d to a const

Comment: Mutating an object is nothing to do with const. ```const a = { b:1 }; a.b = 2;``` mutated.

Comment: i added my logic for the messagescoring function and i don't think I am mutating anything just outputting a score

Comment: Yes it seems like, you are not. Sry I can't see anything else that can be an issue now.